# Event Store on Windows Azure is not accessible externally

Tags: eventstoredb

Try as I might, I'm unable to access my install of Event Store on Windows Azure. I've followed the instructions exactly recommended in [the wiki](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/wiki/Setup-EventStore-on-Windows-Azure). Yes. I've got the ports setup correctly in Azure. But none the less, I cannot connect to it from an external machine.

On a separate machine, if I do curl {{mydomain}}.cloudapp.net, it times out, but on the Azure VM if I do curl localhost, I get Moved (the redirect to the full admin)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you maybe listening only on localhost and not on the VIP/network IP of your Azure VM?
Would explain why the curl to localhost works, but nothing from external.

You'll need to bind to all interfaces, or to your internal ip as described [in a similar google gorups question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/event-store/bind/event-store/WIv9i1izyHM/5awqKBmBPRcJ)

In EventStore 3.0 that would mean --ext-ip 0.0.0.0

Comment: Yeah. The problem turned out to be pretty much that. I've edited your answer to have the exact answer.

Comment: On azure you'll probably need --ext-ip 0.0.0.0 and --http-prefix http://*:2113/ for your server to run